# cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'dw:transform-message'

Tags: maven, mule

I am trying to deploy a mule app on mule standalone 3.7.0 EE, but
when running I occur this error: `cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'dw:transform-message'`

This is my flow:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <mule xmlns:magento="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/magento" xmlns:dw="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/magento http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/magento/current/mule-magento.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd">
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<magento:config name="Magento" username="test" password="test" address="http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v2_soap/" doc:name="Magento"/>
<flow name="proFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="test" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <magento:get-order config-ref="Magento" orderId="100000000" doc:name="Magento"/>
    <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
        <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
         %output application/json
         ---
        {
        orderId: payload.increment_id
        }]]></dw:set-payload>
       </dw:transform-message>
    <set-payload value="#[payload]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
</flow>
</mule>
```

also, I have this dependency in `pom.xml`:

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.weave</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-plugin-weave_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are missing this schema locations:

```
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd
```

Try to add it in xsi:schemaLocation list.

Hope this helps
Regards

Comment: I get this error in standalone: `[http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Option (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException) (org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException)
`

Comment: Ok, so this is than another exception and another question. I suppose the problem you had in your question has been resolved. I suggest you to post another question with the full stack trace so that you keep respecting the rules of stackoverflow and we keep helping you.
Off course don't forget to mark my answer as correct one if it was, I will appreciate it.